# cabinet rack that holds computer, router, and wires

Tags: networking

Is there such a cabinet that will allow me to place my router, computer, devices inside and have all all the power cables plugged inside into a power socket then have one master power cord that gets plugged into the wall. something like this, http://www.datalinksales.com/prod_imgs/network/1915-3-100-08.jpg (see below) but more for a device container that is enclosed.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short Answer: Yes.

Long Answer: Yes, how much do you want to spend?

There are cabinets of varying sizes with shelves and other accessories which accomodate multiple types of equipment. The cabinet accessories include options such as power strips so you can plug in all of your equipment and then plug one "cord" into the wall.

A search on [Amazon](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias=aps&field-keywords=server%20cabinet) for "server cabinet" yields over 2,000 results. I see the first one is a 6 U (or "unit" - a standard within the IT industry) high and costs about 155 dollars.

Comment: i dont have a set budget yet and just looking, what are they called and whats the average price range?

Comment: if i were to make one out of wood, would it be safe? or turn an old cabinet into one?

Comment: @SarmenB. -- I have a plywood box (with clear plastic "door") attached to the firewall in our garage that is used to house our firewall.  Used to contain a short tower box running Linux for a firewall, along with the cable modem and hub, but the Linux box has been replaced with a wireless router.  The box contains two thermostatically-controlled fans blowing out the top (though I think one of the fans died about 5 years ago).

Answer (score 2):

Second hand 19" rack cabinets can be picked up pretty cheaply, you can then source multiple shelves (e.g. http://amzn.com/B001J5S75U) to house router's etc.

You should easily be able to mount power-boards to the shelves then have a main lead exiting an enclosed rack cabinet.

You can also get cases that will fit into the rack cabinet without having to use shelving - http://amzn.com/B008TCUMN6

Remember, ventilation is important!

I personally have a UPS that also provides some powerdistribution;
[image]